# No implicit conversion of String into Integer from JSON output in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Let me start by saying that I'm very new to Ruby and JSON.

In my model file, I'm trying to parse JSON to a hash, then return a specific keys value back to the view.

I'm currently getting the error message "no implicit conversion of String into Integer". My understanding is that the JSON output is returning an array of hashes, therefore I'm trying to access and return the first arrays key value.

app/models/word.rb

```
def self.search(search)
    result_json = Wordnik.word.get_definitions(search)
    result_hash = JSON.parse(result_json.to_json)     # Parse JSON to hash

    definition = result_hash.first["text"]            # return first :text key of the hash
end
```

JSON output from Wordik.word.get_definitions

```
[
      {
        "textProns"=>[],
        "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses"=>[],
        "relatedWords"=>[],
        "labels"=>[],
        "citations"=>[],
        "word"=>"fallacy",
        "text"=>"A false notion.",
        "sequence"=>"0",
        "score"=>0.0,
        "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
        "attributionText"=>"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
       },

      {
        "textProns"=>[],
        "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses"=>[],
        "relatedWords"=>[],
        "labels"=>[],
        "citations"=>[],
        "word"=>"fallacy",
        "text"=>"A statement or an argument based on a false or invalid inference.",
        "sequence"=>"1",
        "score"=>0.0,
        "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
        "attributionText"=>"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      },

      {
        "textProns"=>[],
        "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses"=>[],
        "relatedWords"=>[],
        "labels"=>[],
        "citations"=>[],
        "word"=>"fallacy",
        "text"=>"Incorrectness of reasoning or belief; erroneousness.",
        "sequence"=>"2",
        "score"=>0.0,
        "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
        "attributionText"=>"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      },

      {
        "textProns"=>[],
        "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses"=>[],
        "relatedWords"=>[],
        "labels"=>[],
        "citations"=>[],
        "word"=>"fallacy",
        "text"=>"The quality of being deceptive.",
        "sequence"=>"3",
        "score"=>0.0,
        "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
        "attributionText"=>"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      }
    ]
```

I'm getting the error message "no implicit conversion of String into Integer".

Comment: Copying this data into IRB, and following your code from `result_hash = JSON.parse ...` onward, I get `"A false notion."` as a result. Are you omitting any steps here?

Comment: The data you posted above is indeed an array of hashes.

Comment: That output is from the console when creating a new Word object using the code below in my model file:

'def initialize(name)'
  'self.name = name'
'end'
  
'def definitions'
    'Wordnik.word.get_definitions(self.name)' 
'end'

Comment: However, the Wordnik API documentation specifies that the default format of output data is JSON, so I'm not truly sure what form the data output is in the first line of my self.search method...

Answer (score 0):

First I think there is an issue with your JSON, JSON should use `:` and not `=>`, then I have reformatted the JSON payload to

[
          {
            "textProns":[],
            "sourceDictionary":"ahd-legacy",
            "exampleUses":[],
            "relatedWords":[],
            "labels":[],
            "citations":[],
            "word":"fallacy",
            "text":"A false notion.",
            "sequence":"0",
            "score":0.0,
            "partOfSpeech":"noun",
            "attributionText":"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
           },

```
      {
        "textProns":[],
        "sourceDictionary":"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses":[],
        "relatedWords":[],
        "labels":[],
        "citations":[],
        "word":"fallacy",
        "text":"A statement or an argument based on a false or invalid inference.",
        "sequence":"1",
        "score":0.0,
        "partOfSpeech":"noun",
        "attributionText":"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      },

      {
        "textProns":[],
        "sourceDictionary":"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses":[],
        "relatedWords":[],
        "labels":[],
        "citations":[],
        "word":"fallacy",
        "text":"Incorrectness of reasoning or belief; erroneousness.",
        "sequence":"2",
        "score":0.0,
        "partOfSpeech":"noun",
        "attributionText":"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      },

      {
        "textProns":[],
        "sourceDictionary":"ahd-legacy",
        "exampleUses":[],
        "relatedWords":[],
        "labels":[],
        "citations":[],
        "word":"fallacy",
        "text":"The quality of being deceptive.",
        "sequence":"3",
        "score":0.0,
        "partOfSpeech":"noun",
        "attributionText":"from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"
      }
    ]
```

Code, I copied the payload into a file to parse it, I don't think you need `to_json` any longer if the payload is `JSON`

```
[2] pry(main)> a = JSON.parse(File.read("result.json"))
=> [{"textProns"=>[],
  "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
  "exampleUses"=>[],
  "relatedWords"=>[],
  "labels"=>[],
  "citations"=>[],
  "word"=>"fallacy",
  "text"=>"A false notion.",
  "sequence"=>"0",
  "score"=>0.0,
  "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
  "attributionText"=>
   "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},
 {"textProns"=>[],
  "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
  "exampleUses"=>[],
  "relatedWords"=>[],
  "labels"=>[],
  "citations"=>[],
  "word"=>"fallacy",
  "text"=>"A statement or an argument based on a false or invalid inference.",
  "sequence"=>"1",
  "score"=>0.0,
  "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
  "attributionText"=>
   "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"},
 {"textProns"=>[],
  "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
  "exampleUses"=>[],
  "relatedWords"=>[],
  "labels"=>[],
  "citations"=>[],
  "word"=>"fallacy",
  "text"=>"Incorrectness of reasoning or belief; erroneousness.",
[3] pry(main)> a.first
=> {"textProns"=>[],
 "sourceDictionary"=>"ahd-legacy",
 "exampleUses"=>[],
 "relatedWords"=>[],
 "labels"=>[],
 "citations"=>[],
 "word"=>"fallacy",
 "text"=>"A false notion.",
 "sequence"=>"0",
 "score"=>0.0,
 "partOfSpeech"=>"noun",
 "attributionText"=>
  "from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 4th Edition"}
[4] pry(main)> a.first["text"]
=> "A false notion."
```